# Compress many versions of a text with fast access to each

Tags: compression

Let's say I store many versions of a source code file in a source code repository - maybe 500 historic versions of a 50k source file. So storing the versions directly would take about 12.5 MB (assuming the file grew linearly over time). Naturally though, there is ample room for compression as there will only be slight differences between most successive versions.

What I want is **compact storage** as well as reasonably **quick extraction of any of the versions** at any time.

So we would probably store a list of oft-occuring text chunks, and each version would just contain pointers to the chunks it is made of. To make this really compact, text chunks would be able to defined as concatenations of other chunks.

Is there a well-established compression algorithm that produces this kind of structure? I was not sure what term to search for.

(Bonus points if adding a new version is faster than recompressing the whole set of versions.)

Comment: When I was little, we had something called `zip`.

Comment: @Gabriel. Heh. Yeah but that's gonne be pretty big in this case. I want cross-file compression.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called ["git"](https://git-scm.com/). In fact, that is *exactly* what you want. Including bonus points.

Comment: Thanks, but I want an algorithm, not a tool. You probably refer to git's "pack files" (https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format). It seems they store files as deltas of other files, which is similar to but not exactly what I want, as it will probably get inefficient when you have to follow a long chain of deltas to get to a specific version.

Comment: First, it is very fast. Second, you don't have to store it as a linear history in git. It could be a tree or even a large number of diffs from a single starting file.

Comment: If you diff against a single file, compression suffers. If you diff in a chain, extraction is slowed down. I am looking for a format/algorithm that excels on both fronts. I haven't seen this anywhere yet. OK, thinking about it, the diff chain is pretty doable if decompression is optimized using ropes or such.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there were no usable answers, I came up with my own format today to demonstrate what I mean. I am storing 850 versions of a source file about 20k in size. Usually from one version to the next just one line was added (but there were other changes as well).

If I store these 850 versions in a .zip, it is 4.2 MB big. I want less than that, way less.

My format is line-based. Basically each file version is stored as a list of pointers into a table. Each table entry is either:

- a literal line,
- or a pair of pointers into the table.

In the second case, in decompression, the two pointers have to be followed successively.

Not sure if this description makes sense to you right away, but [the thing works](http://code.botcompany.de/1028167).

The compressor generates a single text file from which each of the 850 versions can be extracted instantly. This text file has a size of 45k.

Finally we can simply gzip this file which gets us down to 18.5k. Quite an improvement from 4.2 MB!

The compressor uses a very simple but effective way to find repeating combinations of lines.

So the answer to the initial question is that there is an algorithm that combines inter-file compression (like .tar.gz) with instant extraction if any contained file (like .zip).

I still don't know how you would call this class of compression algorithms.

Comment: i would call that a "structural compression algorithm" because it uses the structure of text files (lines) to find duplicate chunks